# Why won't my images align horizontally on css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi I have 6 images that I have in my website that are appearing vertically stacked but I want them to be horizontally stacked and center aligned. 4 of the images have captions too that I need to appear right below each image... can someone please help thanks so much

Here is my html:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="container-of-images">
      <img src="chick2.png">

      <figure>
        <img id="img1" src="dice6.png">
        <figcaption>Testing</figcaption>
      </figure>

      <figure>
        <img id="img2" src="dice6.png">
        <figcaption>Testing</figcaption>
      </figure>

      <figure>
        <img id="img3" class="threeChoices" src="dice6.png">
        <figcaption>Testing</figcaption>
      </figure>

      <figure>
        <img id="img4" class="fourChoices" src="dice6.png">
        <figcaption>Testing</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <img src="chick1.png">
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #b6e6bd;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 1% 20%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0 1%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: add align-items:center to img

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS code, the problem I found was that display: inline-block should have been used instead of flex.

```
 

        body {
            background-color: #b6e6bd;
            line-height: 1.6;
        }

        .container-fluid {
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;
            width:100%;
        }

        img {
            width: 100px;
            line-height: 0;
            margin: 0 1%;
            display: inline-block;
            justify-content: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        figcaption {
            text-align:
                center;
            width: 100px;
        }

        figure {
            display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks it works...but actually I used flex so that it would be responsive in mobile version as well...what can I do to make it (don't need the exact solutions but I would need flex and mediaquery right?)

Answer (score 0):

Make your image container a flex element that lays out the content in a row:

```css
.container-of-images {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dispay: inline; or dispay: inline-block; to your css.

```
body {
  background-color: #b6e6bd;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 1% 20%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0 1%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  display: inline;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use flexbox on the container? Try this:

```
.container-of-images {
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your if you add the CSS property `display:flex` to `container-of-images` class it will solve your problem. But you solve be aware of the responsive design for it.

```
.container-of-images {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; /* extra line flex alone can solve your problem */
    justify-content: space-around; /* extra line to space images around */
}
```